# Inner join result of correlated query

Tags: mysql, inner-join, correlated-subquery

I have a query like this

```
SELECT hc_num,client_pow,client_id,date_issued,client_occup 
FROM tbl_health_certificate t1 
WHERE date_issued = 
    (SELECT MAX(date_issued) 
     FROM tbl_health_certificate t2 
     WHERE t2.client_id=t1.client_id) AND year(date_issued) < year(now())
```

Now I wanted the result of that to be joined to another table for me to get some row values particularly the `client_fname` and `client_lname` fields. How will I do that? :)

My tables are structured like this --> [tbl_health_certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pCv2.png) , [tbl_client][2]

[Content of tbl_health_certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pCv2.png)

The result that should be shown are the rows with client_id:
-26
-29

with their client_fname and client_lname from the table tbl_client

Comment: which other table you want to join. ? and what will be join condition?

Comment: Your query should return 0 or 1 row. Is that what you want? Or do you want the most recent row from last year for each client?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after a night's sleep I understand why my answers from yesterday didn't work. I thought the subquery was unnecessary but I was wrong because the values in the aggregated columns would not necessarily come from the same rows as `MAX(tbl_health_certificate.date_issued)`. Also, my sleepy mind didn't realize that `WHERE` narrows the result before the grouping occurs, so that would indeed cause rows from clients whose most recent row is from this year to show up. The "not from this year" condition should be placed in a `HAVING` clause, as I have done below.

This query has one level of nesting less than OP's own solution, so I think it is a good alternative.

```
SELECT t1.hc_num, t1.client_pow, t1.client_id,
    t1.date_issued, t1.client_occup, t4.client_fname, t4.client_lname
FROM tbl_health_certificate t1
JOIN
    (SELECT t2.client_id, MAX(t2.date_issued) AS max_date
    FROM tbl_health_certificate t2
    GROUP BY t2.client_id
    HAVING year(MAX(t2.date_issued)) < year(now())) t3
ON t1.client_id = t3.client_id AND t1.date_issued = t3.max_date
JOIN tbl_client t4 ON t1.client_id = t4.client_id
```

Comment: But it's returning only one row.

Comment: If you could explain what result you are looking for, that would help.

Comment: I want the most recent row for each client and return rows which date_issued is less than the current year(tbl_health_certificate)after that I want to get their client_fname and client_lname which are in another table(tbl_client).

Comment: Are you only interested in clients whose most recent row is older than the current year? Or do you want the most recent row and in addition to that all rows from previous years?

Comment: only in clients whose most recent row is less than the current year

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted. I'm confused.

Comment: I want to get the most recent row for each client and if the date_issued of their most recent row is less than the current year now,return their records. Thank you for your patience Thomaso. I'm still a student that's why :)

Comment: And if the most recent row is in this year, should the fields from `tbl_client` contain null?

Comment: If the most recent row is in this year,it will not be shown. I already got that one.

Comment: Could you maybe update your question with a table of expected results?

Comment: My problem is how will I join the result of

SELECT hc_num,client_pow,client_id,date_issued,client_occup 
FROM tbl_health_certificate t1 
WHERE date_issued = 
    (SELECT MAX(date_issued) 
     FROM tbl_health_certificate t2 
     WHERE t2.client_id=t1.client_id) AND year(date_issued) < year(now()) 

to another table

Comment: Yes, I read that in your question, but as you can see from the length of our conversation, your question is not clear. Joining is done with `JOIN`.

Comment: My answer as it is now should give the right result.

Comment: What if sql mode is set to strict on the mysql server?

Comment: 4 rows are being shown @Tomaso rows with client id 23,14,26,29. That's not the result that I want :(

Comment: That's strange. What is the result of `select year(now());`?

Comment: Just checking. Not sure what's wrong with my query, sorry.

Comment: #SOLVED

SELECT * from tbl_client c1 INNER JOIN(SELECT hc_num,client_pow,client_id,date_issued,client_occup FROM tbl_health_certificate t1 WHERE date_issued = (SELECT MAX(date_issued) FROM tbl_health_certificate t2 WHERE t2.client_id=t1.client_id) AND year(date_issued) < year(now())) c2 ON c1.client_id = c2.client_id

Comment: Thanks for giving your solution. I have updated my answer with an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Have modified few lines.

```
select table1.* , table2.* from
(SELECT hc_num,client_pow,client_id,date_issued,client_occup 
FROM tbl_health_certificate t1,
(SELECT MAX(date_issued) date_issued_max
     FROM tbl_health_certificate t2 group by client_id) t2
WHERE t1.date_issued = t2.date_issued_max
AND year(date_issued) < year(now())) table1
left/right/full outer join -- use appropriate join
tbl_client table2 ON table1.client_id = table2.client_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the query would be like this:

```
SELECT 
t2.client_fname, t2.client_lname, t1.hc_num, t1.client_pow,
t1.client_id, MAX(t1.date_issued) as 'date_issued', t1.client_occup 
FROM tbl_health_certificate t1 INNER JOIN 
tbl_client t2 ON t2.client_id = t1.client_id
WHERE year(t1.date_issued) < year(now())
GROUP BY t1.client_id
```

A MAX with a GROUP BY would help and then whatever row result from the t1 would join immediately to the tbl_client to retrieve client information.

Comment: You have a typo tc should be t2. But it's not getting the latest record of the client but it's already retrieving the client information from the tbl_client.

Comment: I am wondering what you meant by latest record of the client. For example, today's year is 2015, so because of `year(t1.date_issued) < year(now())` condition, it should only look for MAX year from previous year.